# How To Use a Loop To Add Months in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a query that will add the next month from the latest month in the dataset.

What I would like is a SQL query that will continue to add months for an entire year and reset. So a total of 12 months from the latest month in the data.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  PERIOD,
  MNTH_DISP,
add_months(PERIOD,+1) newmnth
FROM FI_CHANNEL_HIER 
where period = (select max(period) from  FI_CHANNEL_HIER)  
;
```

What I'm assuming is that I would some sort of while loop or for loop so that every time I run the query the `NEWMNTH` column gets the next month.

Comment: Please tell us why you have the tags `mysql` and `sql-server`?

Comment: To better understand the problem, you need a solution which will generate 12 rows of data starting from Jun/01/2017 till Jun/01/2018 ?

Answer (score 1):

This might give you an idea

```
SQL> select add_Months(sysdate, level) result
  2  from dual
  3  connect by level <= 12;
12.02.2018 22:23
12.03.2018 22:23
12.04.2018 22:23
12.05.2018 22:23
12.06.2018 22:23
12.07.2018 22:23
12.08.2018 22:23
12.09.2018 22:23
12.10.2018 22:23
12.11.2018 22:23
12.12.2018 22:23
12.01.2019 22:23

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```